# How can I use useState to conditionally render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to use useState to conditionally render a div but for the life of me I can not figure out how to do it. I think I am close but I can not see what I am doing wrong, I have entirely misunderstood how to do this. What am I doing wrong? I have written this and it does not work..

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faWindowClose } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

function ElementMenuHeader() {
const [elementMenuOpenClose, setElementMenuOpenClose] = useState(true)
const handleClick = () => setElementMenuOpenClose(false)

return (
    <div id="App-Close-Element-Menu-Container"
    style={{ display: elementMenuOpenClose ? 'block' : 'none'}}
    >
    <button id="App-Close-Element-Menu"
        onClick={() => handleClick }
    >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWindowClose} />
    </button>
    </div>
);
}

export default ElementMenuHeader
```

Ideally I would like to be able to set the state of `elementMenuOpenClose` from other components too, but I will cross this bridge first I think.

Comment: `onClick={() => handleClick }`. This will never call handleClick.  Did you perhaps mean to do `onClick={() => handleClick()}` or `onClick={handleClick}`?

Comment: Yes mate! That solved the problem. I thought that onClick events in react had to be "referenced" from a const or variable ie without the `()` at the end of the function name to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: In addition, I'm assuming you are trying to flip open/close so change handleClick to `handleClick = () => setElementMenuOpenClose(v => !v)`

Comment: @SILENT where is that 'v' coming from?

Comment: @Marley you need to pass a function reference into the prop. This tells react what function you'd like to be called when the event happens. So `onClick={handleClick}` means "when the click happens, call handleClick". `onClick={() => handleClick()}` means "when the click happens, call the function i've just created who's text is  `() => handleClick()`

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a ternary operator and check a against the state in the operator condition return the div you would like based on the state:

```
{(elementMenuOpenClose? <div>some tags A </div>: <div>Some tags B </div>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have a parent component of `ElementMenuHeader`.
Let's say that is `ParentElementMenuHeader`.

Inside `ParentElementMenuHeader` component, you can define like

```
const ParentElementMenuHeader = () => {
 const [elementMenuOpenClose, setElementMenuOpenClose] = useState(true);
 ...
 return (
  ...
   {elementMenuOpenClose && (
    <ElementMenuHeader
     setElementMenuOpenClose={setElementMenuOpenClose}
     ...
   />
   )}
  ...
 );
}
```

Inside ElementMenuHeader component,

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faWindowClose } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

function ElementMenuHeader({setElementMenuOpenClose}) {
 const handleClick = () => setElementMenuOpenClose(false)

 return (
     <div id="App-Close-Element-Menu-Container">
      <button id="App-Close-Element-Menu" onClick={handleClick}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faWindowClose} />
      </button>
     </div>
 );
}

export default ElementMenuHeader
```